# NSTableView: detecting a mouse click together with the row and column

Tags: cocoa, swift, cell, nstableview, mouseclick-event

I'm trying to detect when a mouse click occurs in an NSTableView, and when it does, to determine the row and column of the cell that was clicked.

So far I've tried to use NSTableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification, but there are two problems:

1. It only triggers when the selection changes, whereas I want every mouse click, even if it is on the currently selected row.
2. The clickedRow and clickedColumn properties of NSTableView are both -1 when my delegate is called.

Is there a better (and correct) way of doing this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To catch the user clicking a row (only, when the user clicks a row, not when it is selected programmatically) :

**Subclass your NSTableView and declare a protocol**

*MyTableView.h*

```
@protocol ExtendedTableViewDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView didClickedRow:(NSInteger)row;

@end

@interface MyTableView : NSTableView

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ExtendedTableViewDelegate> extendedDelegate;

@end
```

*MyTableView.m*

**Handle the mouse down event** (note, the delegate callback is not called when the user clicks outside, maybe you want to handle that too, in that case, just comment out the condition "`if (clickedRow != -1)`")

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

    NSPoint globalLocation = [theEvent locationInWindow];
    NSPoint localLocation = [self convertPoint:globalLocation fromView:nil];
    NSInteger clickedRow = [self rowAtPoint:localLocation];

    [super mouseDown:theEvent];

    if (clickedRow != -1) {
        [self.extendedDelegate tableView:self didClickedRow:clickedRow];
    }
}
```

**Make your WC, VC conform to ExtendedTableViewDelegate**.

```
@interface MyViewController : DocumentBaseViewController<ExtendedTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDelegate,  NSTableViewDataSource>
```

**set the extendedDelegate of the MyTableView to your WC, VC (MyViewController)**

somewhere in *MyTableView.m*

```
self.myTableView.extendedDelegate = self
```

**Implement the callback in delegate (MyViewController.m)**

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView didClickedRow:(NSInteger)row {
    // have fun
}
```

Comment: How to handle mouseEntered & mouseExit events? Any ideas?

Answer (score 74):

There is a simple way.

Tested with Swift 3.0.2 on macOS 10.12.2 and Xcode 8.2.1

Let

```
tableView.action = #selector(onItemClicked)
```

Then

```
@objc private func onItemClicked() {
    print("row \(tableView.clickedRow), col \(tableView.clickedColumn) clicked")
}
```

Comment: Seems the best answer.

Comment: Just be sure to set `tableView.target` too.

Comment: Brilliant! This is the best answer indeed

Comment: If you declare the method like `@IBAction private func tableRowWasClicked(_ tableView: NSTableView)`, then in your XIB or storyboard, you can connect the table view's `action` outlet to the method intead of setting the `target` and `action` in code.

Comment: Seems it not only a good answer, it is the way it supposed to work. Because implementing mouseDown and similar have to deal with a lot of coordinates that shift when the table is placed inside a NSScrollView.

Comment: Excellent answer and it appears not to be limited to Swift, but also applies to Objective C

Answer (score 9):

I would prefer doing as follows.

Override

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView shouldSelectRow:(NSInteger)row;
```

Provide super implementation;

```
RequiredRow = row;
RequiredColumn = [tableView clickedColumn];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is triggered not only by the user action, as stated in the question "I'm trying to detect when a mouse click occurs in an NSTableView, and when it does, to determine the row and column of the cell that was clicked" but also every time the selection changes programaticly

Comment: This also gets triggered when the user does actions other than click, e.g. pressing Spacebar or typing a letter key while the list has focus.

Answer (score 7):

If someone is looking for a **Swift 3/4/5** version of Peter Lapisu's answer:

Add an extension for the NSTableView (NSTableView+Clickable.swift):

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa

extension NSTableView {
    open override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        let globalLocation = event.locationInWindow
        let localLocation = self.convert(globalLocation, from: nil)
        let clickedRow = self.row(at: localLocation)

        super.mouseDown(with: event)

        if (clickedRow != -1) {
            (self.delegate as? NSTableViewClickableDelegate)?.tableView(self, didClickRow: clickedRow)
        }
    }
}

protocol NSTableViewClickableDelegate: NSTableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, didClickRow row: Int)
}
```

Then to use it, make sure you implement the new delegate protocol:

```
extension MyViewController: NSTableViewClickableDelegate {
    @nonobjc func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, didClickRow row: Int) {
        Swift.print("Clicked row \(row)")
    }
}
```

The `@nonobjc` attribute silences the warning about it being close to didClick.

Comment: It works, but When clicking on item, nothing selected

Answer (score 4):

Just in case someone was looking for it in **SWIFT** and / or for **NSOutlineView**.

Based on @Peter Lapisu instructions.

```
class MYOutlineViewDelegate: NSOutlineView, NSOutlineViewDelegate,NSOutlineViewDataSource{
//....
}    
extension MYOutlineViewDelegate{
    func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, didClickTableRow item: AnyObject?) {
        //Click stuff
    }

    override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        let globalLocation:NSPoint  = theEvent.locationInWindow
        let localLocation:NSPoint  = self.convertPoint(globalLocation, fromView: nil)
        let clickedRow:Int = self.rowAtPoint(localLocation)

        super.mouseDown(theEvent)

        if (clickedRow != -1) {
            self.outlineView(self, didClickTableRow: self.itemAtRow(clickedRow))
        }
    }}
```

Comment: `mouseDown` should not be in your `MYOutlineViewDelegate`

Answer (score -2):

see the **tableViewSelectionIsChanging** notification, here are the the comments from NSTableView.h

/*
Optional -  Called when the selection is about to be changed, but note, tableViewSelectionIsChanging: is only called when mouse events are changing the selection and not keyboard events.
 */

I concede that this might not be the surest way to correlate your mouse clicks, but it is another area to investigate, seeing that you are interested in mouse clicks.

Comment: I don't think this covers this requirement from the question: "I want every mouse click, even if it is on the currently selected row."

Comment: This will fail to fire if you click again on the currently selected row... no good