# Get notified for selecting a row in NSTableView

Tags: macos, nstableview

As of now I am using `tableViewSelectionDidChange` notification to detect when a user clicks on any row in `NSTableView`. But using this notification delegate I need to deselect the selected row `[tableView deselectRow:[tableView selectedRow]]` as it will not notify until another row gets selected.

The problem with this approach is that once I deselect a row `tableViewSelectionDidChange` will get notified again and now I need to check if `selectedRow` is -1 or not(Since no rows are selected after deselecting it will now return -1)

Is there an equivalent for `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in `NSTableView` as in `UITableView` ? If not is there any better way to get notified when selecting the same row ?

Comment: I don't see a problem with your approach, if 3 extra lines gives you what you want, then go ahead and use it.

Comment: I don't understand "I need to deselect the selected row".  That should be automatic shouldn't it?

Comment: @trojanfoe It is automatic only when you select another row, if I select the same row again it wont post the notification. This is acceptable for cell based tables generally, but in my case I need the notification triggered multiple times even though am clicking on the same row. To achieve that I need to deselect row to get multiple notifications.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and ended up here aswell.

I had a scenario where I had a playlist of songs. I wanted to have the state as "selected" in a song but be able to stop that song and play again selecting the tableview's cell.

I ended up using a solution I saw [here in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560509/nstableview-detecting-a-mouse-click-together-with-the-row-and-column) by [Peter Lapisu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/533422/peter-lapisu).

Basically Peter suggests to extend the tableview create an extendedDelegate property that has the method `- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView didClickedRow:(NSInteger)row;`. Then just override the `mouseDown` event like this :

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

    NSPoint globalLocation = [theEvent locationInWindow];
    NSPoint localLocation = [self convertPoint:globalLocation fromView:nil];
    NSInteger clickedRow = [self rowAtPoint:localLocation];

    [super mouseDown:theEvent];

    if (clickedRow != -1) {
        [self.extendedDelegate tableView:self didClickedRow:clickedRow];
    }
}
```