# NSTableView row is not clickable second time

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am very new to the `macOS` environment. I am detecting a click in `NSTableView` using this method.

```
  func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, shouldSelectRow row: Int) -> Bool {
}
```

Which works well and fine, but the problem is that when I click on the first time the tableView call this method and performs the corresponding action, when I click second time on the row, this method is not getting called. Something strange happening.

You guys have any thoughts? Do I have to deselect rows? I tried deselecting a row and deselecting all rows in this method, but that didn't help me. I am using a `view based tableView`

Comment: Do you need the rows to be selected? If not, you may return `false` from the function.

Comment: Actually that method is used to tell the table view which row can be selected by returning `true` or `false`.

Comment: So which method should I use for detecting a click on tableView row, I don't want the row to be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may return `false` in your function:

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, shouldSelectRow row: Int) -> Bool {
   print("Should select row: \(row)")
   return false
}
```

There's a more elegant and correct solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19661253/758990). It's more work, but I'd recommend going that way.