# NSView's convert(_:to:), convert "from" or "into"?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, nsview, nsoutlineview

I've seen the usage like this in a subclass of an `NSOutlineView`

```
override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    super.mouseDown(with: event)

    let location = self.convert(
        event.locationInWindow,
        to: nil)
    let clickedRow = self.row(at: location)
}
```

The documentation of `convert(_:to:)` says it

> Converts a point from the view’s coordinate system to that of a given
>   view.

So what I understood is it returns a point in the view (as the argument)'s coordinate system. In the above example, it's the window's.

The doc of `row(at:)` of `NSTableView` sasys it receives:

> A point in the coordinate system of the table view.

I'm confused by the English here.

A related question is here: [NSTableView: detecting a mouse click together with the row and column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560509/nstableview-detecting-a-mouse-click-together-with-the-row-and-column)

### Edit

Thanks to @Willeke's pointing out there's the sister of `convert(_:to:)`, `convert(_:from:)`. It's a coincidence that `convert(_:to:)` also works in my case. But I should have used `convert(_:from:)`. I overlooked the linked example.

Comment: Does this code work? The Objective-C code in the linked question uses `convert(_:from:)`.

Comment: Yes, the `clickedRow` is the row clicked.

Comment: printed the **converted** and **original** points: There's a toolbar above the `outlineView`. The difference between the results are smaller than what I expected.
“from”: Clicked (129.6484375, 41.46484375) (128.6484375, 371.53515625)
“to”: Clicked (127.734375, 43.9453125) (128.734375, 369.0546875)

I should have used the "from" one. But it's surprising that the `to` one also works coincidentally.