# Custom `NSOutlineView` doesn't show context menu when right clicked

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I'm implementing the rename/editing function in an `NSOutlineView`. The basic implementation is like:

```
@objc func renameAction() {
    let row = outlineView.clickedRow
    let rowView = outlineView.view(
        atColumn: 0,
        row: row,
        makeIfNecessary: false) as! NSTableCellView

    rowView.textField!.isEditable = true
    rowView.window?.makeFirstResponder(rowView.textField!)
}
```

A `mouseDown:` is handled in the `NSOutlineView` so that the `NSTextField` can quit editing mode when clicking on the row that is being edited.
The idea of using a custom delegate is from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560509/nstableview-detecting-a-mouse-click-together-with-the-row-and-column)

```
override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    super.mouseDown(with: event)
    let localLocation = self.convert(
        event.locationInWindow,
        from: nil)

    let clickedRow = self.row(at: localLocation)
    #if DEBUG
        print(#file, #line, clickedRow)
    #endif
    if clickedRow != -1 {
        self.extendedDelegate?.didClickRow(clickedRow)
    }
}
```

In the delegate:

```
func didClickRow(_ row: Int) {
    //... get the textField
    textField.isEditable = false
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    textField.window?.makeFirstResponder(
        textField.window?.contentView
    )
}
```

**The strange thing is** I can right click on an `NSTableCellView`(including both an icon and an `NSTextField`) to get the context menu **before** a left click on ANY row. After the left click, I can only get the context menu by right clicking anywhere outside the `NSTableCellView` (of any row, no matter it's the clicked one or not) but inside the row (the blank areas surrouding the `NSTableCellView`).

### Screenshots

Before any left clicking, right clicking on the `NSTableCellView` gets the menu:

[image: Right clicked to get a menu]

After a left clicking on any row, right click doesn't work "on" all the `NSTableCellView`s, but still works on the blank area of the row.

[image: Right clicked on the "CG" but got nother] // No menu upon clicking on the `NSTableCellView`. But the menu will appear when clicking on the blank areas of the row.

### Update:

I found that if the overriding `mouseDown:` is commented out, (as expected) there's no issue. But that will throw the ability to end editing by clicking on the current row.

Comment: Don't call `resignFirstResponder`, `makeFirstResponder` will do that. Do `isEditable = false` after moving the first responder. Don't make `contentView` first responder unless `contentView` can be the first responder. Instead, make the outline view or the window first responder.

Comment: Thank you! This works! I also tried not moving the `isEditable = false`, it also works. Is there anything special for the order?

Comment: I think so. The text field probably can't be the first responder if `isEditable` and `isSelectable` are `false`.